# For feature selection, do we use Chi-squared with Mutual Information together?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-extraction, mutual-information, chi-square-test

Or do we only choose one out of two for categorical data.

Comment: [A post of mine from earlier today addresses some issues with this kind of variable screening.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/575749/247274) While I address the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, the same issues arise if you demand a certain mutual information before you're willing to include a variable. // [Feature selection in general is fraught with problems.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18214/247274)

Answer (score 0):

Usually feature selection is done with mutual information, correlation or conditional entropy. I'm not aware of statistical tests like chi square used for this, especially because the goal is usually to get a score which represents the importance of a feature, not a yes/no answer for every feature.

But in theory one can used whatever method they want. In general individual feature selection is a rough approximation anyway, since it doesn't take into account the contribution of subsets of features together.